# Moving Outlook 2010 PST files to a new location

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I am trying to move my PST files for Outlook 2010 between folders. From what I have read all I have to do is close Outlook, go to the folders and move the file over. Then, when I restart Outlook, I should get an error message. When I hit "okay" it should take me to an Open/Change Data file where I can point the existing file to the new location.

However, when I do this, Outlook doesn't give me the error message and creates the same PST file in the original location.

Any suggestions?

[running Windows 7]

Answer (score 1):

Close Outlook.

Go into `Control Panel>User Accounts>Mail>Data Files` and add the PST (Open File Location and pick the location of the old one, wherever you moved it to). Then set it to the default.

After you re-open Outlook, you can then remove the new, empty one back in `Control Panel>User Accounts>Mail>Data Files` (you will probably have to close Outlook again, but it was important that you opened it once). Alternatively, in the navigation pane, right-click it and just close it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder in your MS outlook with any name and move your all emails inbox to new folder.

and second option is you can take data backup of your outlook mails from User Account.

See the video and follow the steps one by one.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3yTxIuTwg8